# Word2Vector ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am a beginner in machine learning, there might be silly mistake, any help would be appreciated.

I am getting error while execution of below code snippet:

```
def plot_region(x_bounds, y_bounds):
    slice = points[
        (x_bounds[0] <= points.x) &
        (points.x <= x_bounds[1]) &
        (y_bounds[0] <= points.y) &
        (points.y <= y_bounds[1])
        ]   

    ax = slice.plot.scatter("x", "y", s=35, figsize=(10, 8))
    for i, point in slice.iterrows():
        ax.text(point.x + 0.005, point.y + 0.005, point.word, fontsize=11)

plot_region(x_bounds=(4.0,4.2),y_bounds=(-0.5,-0.1))
plot_region(x_bounds=(0, 1), y_bounds=(4, 4.5))
```

**ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric**

Comment: Can you fix your indenting please so someone can make sense of your code?

Comment: Please find the indented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code...just that there are no values in points with x_bounds=(4.0,4.2),y_bounds=(-0.5,-0.1).
Thus the slice is an empty DataFrame. Try printing it.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I removed the `+ 0.005` from the `ax.text(...)` line, giving me the line below:

```
ax.text(point.x, point.y, point.word, fontsize=11)
```